# TableLayout weird behavior in the end of ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, tablelayout

I am creating some `TableLayouts` in a `ScrollView` programmatically and I can change the content of these `TableLayout` by adding/deleting dynamically some `TableRows`.

The thing is that everything works fine except with the last one that is having a strange behavior for no apparent reason.

When I am adding/deleting some `TableRows` in the `TableLayouts` above the "problematic" one there are some cells in it that are suddenly showing the content in columns with one character per columns and going out of the cell without stretching the cell and that thing is making the content unreadable.

I don't know why that is happening, because it's the only one with that issue.
I think that the issue is probably related to the fact that the `ScrollView` is resizing itself when the content in it is changing and as the "problematic" `TableLayout` is at the end of the `ScrollView` it is causing some unexpected changement.

How am I supposed to solve that issue ?

*Code :*

```
private List<List<View>> addModifiableLinesToView(final TableLayout view, final String fichier,
                                                  final int[] ordreVoulu, final TreeMap<String,ArrayList> map, final RadioGroup rg) {
    final List<List<View>> listRes = new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        //Recherche de valeurs dans le fichier CSV du module en question ex: csv_bt.csv
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                "/" + folder_main + "/" + imported_data + "/" + fichier);
        CSVFile csv = new CSVFile(is);
        List<String[]> tableau = csv.findLines(indicePoste.getText().toString());
        List<View> tempList;

        //Pour chaque ligne avec le bon numéro de poste trouvé dans le csv
        for (String[] s : tableau) {
            tempList = new ArrayList<>();
            //met les valeurs dans le bon ordre pour les ajouter au tableau
            String[] vals = filtreValeurs(s, ordreVoulu);
            final TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            int n = 0;
            //ajoute les valeurs récupérées a une ligne du tableau
            for (String valeur : vals) {

                View divider = new View(getApplicationContext());
                divider.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                divider.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

                final ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher = new ViewSwitcher(getApplicationContext());

                TextView t = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                t.setLayoutParams(params1);
                t.setMaxWidth(0);
                if(fichier.equals("csv_amm.csv") && n == 3)
                {
                    valeur = valeur.trim();
                    int val = !valeur.equals("")?Integer.parseInt(valeur) : 0;
                    AMMValue ammval = new AMMValue(val);
                    t.setText(ammval.getLibelle());
                }
                else
                    t.setText(valeur);

                t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                t.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                t.setTextSize(14);
                t.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                t.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1)
                            viewSwitcher.showNext();
                    }
                });

                viewSwitcher.addView(t,
                        new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f));

                final String key = (String)map.keySet().toArray()[n];

                if(key.contains("EditText"))
                {
                    final EditText e = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    e.setLayoutParams(params2);
                    e.setSingleLine();
                    e.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
                    e.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
                    e.setMaxWidth(0);
                    e.setTextSize(14);
                    e.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                    e.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    //En fonction de la valeur va afficher un clavier numérique ou non
                    if(key.contains("Number"))
                        e.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                    else if(key.contains("Text"))
                        e.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                    /*
                     *TextChangedListener qui permet de retourner au mode "TextView"
                     *quand on supprime tout ce qui à été écris
                     */
                    e.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                            if(e.length() == 0)
                            {
                                viewSwitcher.showPrevious();
                                cacherClavierVirtuel();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                        }
                    });

                    viewSwitcher.addView(e,
                            new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f));
                }
                else if (key.contains("Spinner"))
                {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            final Spinner spin = new Spinner(getApplicationContext());
                            spin.getBackground().setColorFilter(
                                    getResources().getColor(R.color.noir),
                                    PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                            spin.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
                            spin.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            spin.setPopupBackgroundResource(R.color.blanc);
                            spin.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                            ArrayList<String> list = map.get(key);
                            final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                                    MainActivity.this,
                                    R.layout.spinner_adapter,
                                    list);
                            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
                                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            spin.setAdapter(adapter);

                            //Set de la selection à 1 pour ne pas annuler tout de suite
                            spin.setSelection(1);
                            /* ItemListener qui va retourner le ViewSwitcher en mode
                             * affichage si l'on selectionne la valeur index 0 qui
                             * correspond à "Annuler" */
                            spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                                    new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onItemSelected(
                                                AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                                            ((TextView) adapterView.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(14);
                                            if (adapterView.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0 && rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
                                                spin.setSelection(1);
                                                viewSwitcher.showPrevious();
                                            }

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                                        }
                                    });

                            viewSwitcher.addView(spin,
                                    new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f));
                        }
                    });
                }


                tempList.add(viewSwitcher);

                row.addView(divider,
                        new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                row.addView(viewSwitcher,
                        new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f));
                n++;
            }

            //separateur en fin de ligne
            View divider = new View(getApplicationContext());
            divider.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            divider.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            row.addView(divider,
                    new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    view.addView(row);
                }
            });

            //separateur horizontal
            final View dividerH = new View(getApplicationContext());
            dividerH.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    3));
            dividerH.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    view.addView(dividerH, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            3));
                }
            });
            listRes.add(tempList);
        }
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Erreur de format du CSV pour : " + view.getTag().toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return listRes;
```

Comment: Please post you code. We can't help you without it !

Comment: I know it's not the answer you are expecting, but maybe it's better to use RecyclerView with elements based on ConstraintLayout? Or even LinearLayout(vertical) with custom views based on CostraintLayout? It will give you total control on layout and behavior.